# Angular and JSON protection with PHP

Tags: php, json, angularjs

In the $http documentation, I'm told to prefix my response with `)]}',\n` how can I do that in PHP? And how do I access the returned data object once done?

```
        error(function(data, status, headers, config) {  
            $scope.error = data.error;
        });


echo json_encode(array('error' => $error)); //You messed up Leroy!
```

Comment: don't confuse specific error message sent from server with `$http` error. Unless headers are changed you would read your output in success callback

Comment: Your comment isn't really apart of the issue unfortunately, I use the headers appropriately.

Comment: just mentioning it...is a common misconception that simply echoing an array that contains your application error messages should trigger ajax error

Answer (score 0):

The following should work.

```
echo ")]}',\n" . json_encode(array('error' => $error));
```

About angular: I think the function you have is correct. But if it's not working, it's useful to `console.log(data)`, and find, which structure it has.